# UIView with image

Tags: ios, uiview

In my application i have `UIViews` with image as their `backgroundColor`.
*Opaque* is set to 1.0 and `backgroundColor` to white. But in simulator they still displayed with red flag in color blended layers mode:

[image]

Is there a way to make them green?

Same trouble with UIView which have background from UIColor with 1.0 Alpha channel.

Comment: are the image PNG with transparent background?

Comment: `opaque` is not a float; it's a Bool. It does not govern opacity; it is just a hint to the drawing system. You may be doing this wrong... Show your code please!

Comment: Just mistake, of course bool :)Alpha channel in png was my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the background colour of the `UIImageView` will not have any effect on this.

All you are doing is saying "merge the transparent image colour with this background colour" instead of "merge the transparent colour with the colour underneath the image view".

It still has to do the same rendering pass for the transparency.

The best way to do this is to take the colour of whatever is underneath the `UIImageView` ad use that as the background of the png image instead of having a transparent png.

This is the only way to stop this.